# how to get the count of 1's and 0's (which are the values of col2) for each type of value of the row in the col1 when the col3 value is >= 95?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

col1 contains the names of fields such as NAME, CITY and STATE.
col2 contains the values 1 and 0 for each value of col1,
col3 contains the values ranging from 50 to 100

The following is the representation:

```
col1    col2    col3
---------------------
NAME    1        96
NAME    1        99
CITY    0        69
CITY    1        97
STATE   1        98
STATE   0        59
```

The desired output is that I need to count the number of 1s and 0s for each type of value of col1 that are greater than or equal to 95 in col3.
the following could give the count for all the values of col1, that is, NAME, CITY, STATE. but the requirement is to get the count for each field.

```
df['col3'].value_counts()[0])
```

The following piece of code will filter for the condition that it should have the value above 95.

```
filt = (df['col1'] == 'NAME') | (df['col3'] > 95)
```

This is what I've tried. Please let me know if anyone can help me with the desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter on the rows where col3 is greater than 95:

```
df.loc[df['col3'] > 95]

    col1  col2  col3
0   NAME     1    96
1   NAME     1    99
3   CITY     1    97
4  STATE     1    98
```

Then use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on this, grouping by col1 and col2 using [`count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

```
df.loc[df['col3'] > 95].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count()

            col3
col1  col2      
CITY  1        1
NAME  1        2
STATE 1        1
```

Answer (score 3):

If need count `0` if no match create helper boolean column and aggregate `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['col3'] > 95)
         .groupby(['col1','col2'])['new']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
    col1  col2  count
0   CITY     0      0
1   CITY     1      1
2   NAME     1      2
3  STATE     0      0
4  STATE     1      1
```

But if dont need `0` counts first filter and then aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df2 = df[df['col3'] > 95].groupby(['col1','col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
    col1  col2  count
0   CITY     1      1
1   NAME     1      2
2  STATE     1      1
```